# How can I customize default return value of date in Laravel

Tags: date, laravel-4

In my project, I can retrieve created at for each post as $post->created_at but, is there way to customize it from model?

I mean if I call `$post->created_at`, Laravel will return result of `date("d F Y H:i", strtotime($date))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can.

in your POST model add the following accessor:

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value)
 {
     return date("d F Y H:i", strtotime($value));
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a doc for something related like that? Another I need to reparse `$post->body` by default. Is that means can I do something like `getBodyAttribute($value)`? Also another one I need to something like `$post->body->markdown()`. This one will handle markdown.

Comment: Thanks again. But still I have last question. How can I do `$post->body->markdown()`, if you think it's unrelated to this topic, I can ask another question.

Comment: That will be better as new one looks different and need some description as well.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Also Use Carbon Object

```
          // Motters To Use Created To data Only
      public function getCreatedAtAttribute($date)
      {
          return \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date)->format('Y-m-d');
      }

      public function getUpdatedAtAttribute($date)
      {
          return \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date)->format('Y-m-d');
      }
```